# How to make a search input field to search table data?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML table with JSON data, I am trying to have an search input field to search my html table data.

I only want to search the tbody elements of the table not thead,but here in my code its not working.

I have given a class `filterdata` in my code from where the body code starts but search is not working.

Here is my code :

**Snippet**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var tableValue = [{
      "Distributor Name": "MAIYAS RESTAURANTS PVT LTD",
      "User Name": "admin",
      "User LoginId": "admin",
      "User Password": "admin",
      "User role": "DISTRIBUTOR",
      "Active": "Y"
    },
    {
      "Distributor Name": "MAIYAS RESTAURANTS PVT LTD",
      "User Name": "maiyas",
      "User LoginId": "maiyas",
      "User Password": "maiyas",
      "User role": "DISTRIBUTOR",
      "Active": "Y"
    },
    {
      "Distributor Name": "CHEF BAKERS",
      "User Name": "cbadmin",
      "User LoginId": "cbadmin",
      "User Password": "cbadmin",
      "User role": "DISTRIBUTOR",
      "Active": "Y"
    },
    {
      "Distributor Name": "CHEF BAKERS",
      "User Name": "cbaker",
      "User LoginId": "cbaker",
      "User Password": "cbaker",
      "User role": "DISTRIBUTOR",
      "Active": "Y"
    },
    {
      "Distributor Name": "JAYANAGAR MAIYAS RESTAURANTS PVT LTD",
      "User Name": "jayanagar",
      "User LoginId": "jayanagar",
      "User Password": "jayanagar",
      "User role": "DISTRIBUTOR",
      "Active": "Y"
    },
    {
      "Distributor Name": "MALLESHWARAM MAIYAS RESTAURANTS PVT LTD",
      "User Name": "malleswaram",
      "User LoginId": "malleswaram",
      "User Password": "malleswaram",
      "User role": "DISTRIBUTOR",
      "Active": "Y"
    },
    {
      "Distributor Name": "KOLAR MAIYAS RESTAURANTS PVT LTD",
      "User Name": "kolar",
      "User LoginId": "kolar",
      "User Password": "kolar",
      "User role": "DISTRIBUTOR",
      "Active": "Y"
    }
  ]

  function addTable(tableValue) {
    var col = Object.keys(tableValue[0]);
    var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length;
    var num = col.splice(0, countNum);
    col = col.concat(num);
    var table = document.createElement("table");
    var tr = table.insertRow(-1);
    for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) { //this one to make  thead
      var th = document.createElement("th");
      th.innerHTML = col[i];
      tr.classList.add("text-center");
      tr.appendChild(th);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < tableValue.length; i++) { // thid one to make tbody
      tr = table.insertRow(-1);
      tr.classList.add("filterData"); //hear i am adding the class in body
      for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
        var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
        var tabledata = tableValue[i][col[j]];
        if (tabledata && !isNaN(tabledata)) {
          tabledata = parseInt(tabledata);
          tabCell.classList.add("text-right");
        }
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
      }
      var divContainer = document.getElementById("mrpl");
      divContainer.innerHTML = "";
      divContainer.appendChild(table);
      table.classList.add("table");
      table.classList.add("table-striped");
      table.classList.add("table-bordered");
      table.classList.add("table-hover");
    }
  }
  addTable(tableValue)
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $(".filterData tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
<div id="mrpl"></div>
```

I am going to right approach but what I am doing wrong I don't know.

Note: for some reasons I can't use `dataTables`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of ways to do this. here is one possible example.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var tableValue = [{
      "Distributor Name": "MAIYAS RESTAURANTS PVT LTD",
      "User Name": "admin",
      "User LoginId": "admin",
      "User Password": "admin",
      "User role": "DISTRIBUTOR",
      "Active": "Y"
    },
    {
      "Distributor Name": "MAIYAS RESTAURANTS PVT LTD",
      "User Name": "maiyas",
      "User LoginId": "maiyas",
      "User Password": "maiyas",
      "User role": "DISTRIBUTOR",
      "Active": "Y"
    },
    {
      "Distributor Name": "CHEF BAKERS",
      "User Name": "cbadmin",
      "User LoginId": "cbadmin",
      "User Password": "cbadmin",
      "User role": "DISTRIBUTOR",
      "Active": "Y"
    },
    {
      "Distributor Name": "CHEF BAKERS",
      "User Name": "cbaker",
      "User LoginId": "cbaker",
      "User Password": "cbaker",
      "User role": "DISTRIBUTOR",
      "Active": "Y"
    },
    {
      "Distributor Name": "JAYANAGAR MAIYAS RESTAURANTS PVT LTD",
      "User Name": "jayanagar",
      "User LoginId": "jayanagar",
      "User Password": "jayanagar",
      "User role": "DISTRIBUTOR",
      "Active": "Y"
    },
    {
      "Distributor Name": "MALLESHWARAM MAIYAS RESTAURANTS PVT LTD",
      "User Name": "malleswaram",
      "User LoginId": "malleswaram",
      "User Password": "malleswaram",
      "User role": "DISTRIBUTOR",
      "Active": "Y"
    },
    {
      "Distributor Name": "KOLAR MAIYAS RESTAURANTS PVT LTD",
      "User Name": "kolar",
      "User LoginId": "kolar",
      "User Password": "kolar",
      "User role": "DISTRIBUTOR",
      "Active": "Y"
    }
  ]

  function addTable(tableValue) {
    var col = Object.keys(tableValue[0]);
    var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length;
    var num = col.splice(0, countNum);
    col = col.concat(num);
    var table = document.createElement("table");
    var tr = table.insertRow(-1);
    for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) { //this one to make  thead
      var th = document.createElement("th");
      th.innerHTML = col[i];
      tr.classList.add("text-center");
      tr.appendChild(th);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < tableValue.length; i++) { // thid one to make tbody
      tr = table.insertRow(-1);
      tr.classList.add("filterData"); //hear i am adding the class in body
      for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
        var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
        var tabledata = tableValue[i][col[j]];
        if (tabledata && !isNaN(tabledata)) {
          tabledata = parseInt(tabledata);
          tabCell.classList.add("text-right");
        }
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
      }
      var divContainer = document.getElementById("mrpl");
      divContainer.innerHTML = "";
      divContainer.appendChild(table);
      table.classList.add("table");
      table.classList.add("table-striped");
      table.classList.add("table-bordered");
      table.classList.add("table-hover");
    }
  }
  addTable(tableValue)
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var q = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    if (q === "") {
      $(".filterData").show();
      return true;
    }
    $(".filterData").hide().filter(function(i, el) {
      var d = $(el).text().trim().toLowerCase();
      console.log(q, d, d.indexOf(q));
      return (d.indexOf(q) > -1);
    }).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
<div id="mrpl"></div>
```

You can do it with `.filter()`. So filter will reduce the selected items based on the filter. `.filterData` is all the Rows, so we hide them all first. Then we filter the rows to the ones that contain the query, looking for the text of the first cell. We then show those specific rows.

If the user removes the entry, show all rows.

I left the other code alone, yet it too can be improved.

Hope that helps.

Comment: hey ..no no, this one is only searching as `Distributor Name` which is not the right output, i am trying to make search for all paramter like if i search as `admin` it should show the row containing  admin, but here it is not working like that

Comment: @viveksingh easy to fix. Done.